# Iterating over nested object

Tags: javascript

I have a nested object with structure as follows:

```
{
 "sensors": [{
     "probe": "PROBENAME",
     "sensor": "SENSORNAME",
     "status": "STATUS"
 }, {
     "probe": "PROBENAME",
     "sensor": "SENSORNAME",
     "status": "STATUS"
 }]
}
```

Is there a good way to actually iterate over this in such a way that I only get the "probes" and "sensors." There are 1000s of each, and I want to be able to grab all of them. For some reason, whenever I iterate over the structure, I just get [object][object] in the return.

Comment: This has nothing to do with either JSON or node.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This? Or am I missing something?

```
yourObj.sensors.forEach(function(item){
  console.log(item.probe, item.sensor);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newObj = {sensors: obj.sensors.map(({sensor, probe} => ({sensor, probe}))};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = {
 "sensors": [{
 "probe": "PROBENAME",
 "sensor": "SENSORNAME",
 "status": "STATUS"
}, {
 "probe": "PROBENAME",
 "sensor": "SENSORNAME",
 "status": "STATUS"
}]
}

var output = []
input.sensors.forEach(function(sensor){
 output.push({
  probes : sensor.probe,
  sensor : sensor.sensor
 })

});

console.log(output)
```